# How to lay out scrollable iPhone view

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, view, uiscrollview

I need advice on the most pragmatic way to layout the following view. As you can see from the image attached, I have a static logo and text that appears at the top of the view, followed by a variable number of items.

Initially, I was going to use a TableView for the variable number of items, that way I would be able to load any given number of cells at runtime.

My problem is that if I drop a tableView onto this view below my static logo and text, when the user scrolls, the static logo and text will remain fixed. I need both the static logo/text AND the tableView to scroll up.

My next inclination is to use a scrollView, inside which I would place my tableView and static logo.

Is this the most pragmatic way to approach the problem? If so, will there be usability issues when scrolling the scrollView vs scrolling the tableView? In my mind this could get messy.

Any advice on the best way to approach this is greatly appreciated.

[image: content]

Comment: You could still use a tableView and just make the static logo the first row of the table.

Comment: As far as using a UIScrollView all you need to do is add subViews to your UIScrollView as subViews and set the contentSize to the total content height.

Comment: or you could create a sub view with ur desire content and load it in ur scroll view..

Comment: If I stick to using a tableView for the whole view, can I set the height of the first cell independently of the rest?

Comment: +1 for nice screen shot with labels. If only everyone asked questions as clearly as this!

Comment: @Scratcha "can I set the height of the first cell independently" Yes! Look at the UITableViewDelegate methods - `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. I know it's confusing at first, the functionality is all over the place (table view, data source, delegate, cell...).

Comment: You can also use a section table view, and put the logo in the first section, and the rest of the table in the second.  It will do the same thing, but give you a slightly different look.

Comment: Why not make the Static logo on the top a header of a TableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a table view inside of a scroll view is a bad idea and warned against by Apple in their docs. Basically the internal gesture recognizers can conflict and create a clunky user experience. The best path forward would be to go with the tableview (which is a subclass of scroll view) and have two different kinds of cells– one for the logo and one for the repeating contents at the bottom. Make the first cell the logo and adjust the table view's settings to format it to your heart's content.